# Fatal error while exporting a CSV file from webpage

Tags: magento, fatal-error, entity-attribute-value

I'm trying to export an cvs file but I'm having this error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Yesno::setAttribute() in
>   /home/acdistri/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php
>   on line 389

Comment: Please post the code from Abstract.php  lines 350 - 400.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your quick interest in this question... I found the solution... when I install a extension it create an Attribute, then I uninstall the extension because a JavaScript conflict but the attribute stay there and when I was trying to do the export of the products data base it give me that error. I just delete the attribute and now is working all fine.